# Dimension of Vector space over $\Bbb R$ and $ \Bbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be the set of all $4 \times 4$ skew symmetric complex matrix,what is dimension of $A$ over $\Bbb R$?
what about $ \Bbb C$?
In my opinion the answers are 12.
But I'm  not sure.

Is it correct?

Comment: Well, for each entry, you need $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$, so once you have all the entries either below- or above- the diagonal, your entire matrix is given/fixed.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}$ should be more, because for instance, if we look at $2 \times 2$, the off diagonal entry being $1,-1$ vs $i,-i$ is different, as multiplying by a real scalar cannot get one from the other.

Answer (score 1):

The collection of matrices $M_{ij}$ with $a_{ij}=1$ and $a_{ji}=-1$ , for $i\neq j$ and $a_{ii}=0$ will generate the vector space of skew-symmetric $n\times n$ -matrices. These are a total of $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ matrices. You use the sum $\Sigma s_{ij}M_{ij}$, where $S=(s_{ij})$ is your skew-symmetric matric and $(s_{ij})$ is the $(i,j)$-th entry.

Comment: Thanks.I think over  $\Bbb R$ is 24.Is it correct?

Comment: Can you think of a generating set?

Comment: The "generate" should be qualified by "as complex vector space"; the first question asks about a real vector space. Also @user91559, $\frac{4^2-4}2=6$, I don't know how you get from there to $24$.